# How to repackage NVIDIA .run drivers into .deb with DKMS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, driver, package, nvidia

At present, Ubuntu offers the 195.36.24 drivers as `nvidia-current` in their repository. This packaged driver is pretty cool as it uses DKMS so you don't have to keep reinstalling the driver after a new kernel version.

The NVIDIA .run package drivers are at version 257 (beta) but they don't use DKMS so the graphics screws up every time a new kernel is installed and you don't reinstall the driver.

How can I modify the .run to use DKMS and even better, package it as a deb package?

Comment: You can't just get the source .deb and replace it in there?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean; please explain further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this PPA, it seems they have updated drivers: [NVIDIA-VDPAU](https://launchpad.net/~nvidia-vdpau/+archive/ppa)
Maybe it supports DKMS.